# How to extract the first word surrounded by quotes when quotes appear multiple times in LEX

Tags: regex, lex

Hi I am trying to extract the first quoted word when there are multiple quotes in a sentence. However, if I use the regular expression I wrote below, parts I do not want are recognized.

```
%%
^\'[a-z]+\'  printf("%s","");
```

For example, when there is a sentence

> 'apple' banana 'orange'

output:

> banana 'orange'

No matter which regular expression is used, the entire input sentence is output. Below, to check whether 'apple' is recognized, the entire sentence is printed even though this is set to a space. What I want is if there is a string ('apple') that I am looking for, I want to output it as it is.

How to print **only** recognized words?

Comment: You need to add a default rule; your pattern is only matching *'apple'*, but the default rule is matching and outputting everything else.  Any easy way to verify this is change your printf to *printf("<%s>","");*  I bet your output becomes *<> banana 'orange'*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into the default rule a bit more